# give access to /home/$USER/targetfolder only to me and a partner

Tags: permissions, solaris, chmod

I'm working on a server where current users (group=domainusers gid=1002) can read, write and run ONLY our own files.
Because of my kind of permissions I'm not able to run `apt | adduser | addgroup | groupmod`
Is there any way excepting running `chmod -R 777 /home/$USER/targetfolder` for getting what im looking for?
I was wondering about if there is any way of adding my partner as co-propietary of the folder and then run `chmod -R 770 /home/$USER/targetfolder`

PS: Solaris SunOs 5.10 (I know it's kinda deprecated, not my fault)

Edit: Worked out a solution for having a shared space for me and a partner.

Creating a symlink to the target folder and giving it permissions of reading write and execution independently of the permissions of the parent folder. I know it's unsafe but it works for what I'm looking for and unfortunately I'm not able to do anything else.

Comment: I'm removing the Linux tag, as this seems to have nothing to do with linux at all?

Comment: Okey, I have misdescribed Solaris as a Linux based System when it's an UNIX one, my bad.

Comment: no big deal! Just wanted to make sure I'm not missing something! I was a bit confused by `apt` being there, I was assuming Solaris used a different package manager, as I only know `apt` as being the debian Linux package manager.

Comment: The only way to access the Solaris System is through SSHing from a Debian remote host. The Solaris server shares the same FileSystem as the host. So I made a mistake describing the scenario.